# Regex: How can I match something enclosed by certain characters?

Tags: python, sql, regex

I'm looking for a way to select and replace a certain part in my string using python's `re.sub`.

The string in my case would be

```
'SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE "id"=%user.id%;'
```

The content within the `%` signs should be short executable code that returns a number, string, or other.

```py
# having these
user = User(id=123)
'SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE "id"=%user.id%;'

# output should be
'SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE "id"=123;'
```

but also

```py
# having these
user = User(id=123, name="John Smith")
'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE "name"=%user.name.lower().replace(" ", "_")%;'''

# output should be
'''SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE "name"='john_smith';'''
```

I'm very new to regex, so I don't know how to do that. I tried `/%\w+/g`, but this would only match `%user`, instead of `%user.id%`. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
re.sub(r'%([^%]*)%', lambda m: str(eval(m.group(1))), your_string)
```

But I wouldn't recommend it for at least two reasons:

- executing arbitrary code from user input is dangerous
- replacing values as strings into SQL without properly quoting them is also dangerous